# WSO2 AM (1.10.0) ip address redirect

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

The WSO2 AM site has been assigned a domain, puaki-uat.mpi.govt.nz. however, the site will automatically redirect to ip address after typing the domain name, which will results in mismatch signed certificate,

[image: wso21]

Expected always use domain name to match a security certificate,
  [image: wso2_2]

Could please anyone can tell me how to prevent the site from switching to IP address?

Thanks, Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't configured the hostname in carbon.xml. Go to wso2am-1.10.0/repository/conf/carbon.xml and change the following tags.

```
<HostName>puaki-uat.mpi.govt.nz</HostName>

<MgtHostName>puaki-uat.mpi.govt.nz</MgtHostName>
```